# Android,setSpan twice?

Tags: android, spannablestring

Say I have a `SpannableString` that a URLSpan is set for span in it like this:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
ss.setSpan(new URLSpan("com://my.app"), 3, 6,
Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Then I set another URLSpan for that span.But second URLSpan does not work and first one works.I can not use `ss.removeSpan(what);` because I do not want to remove all URLSpans.How I can solve this problem?

Comment: do you use the same span objects twice?

Comment: @pskink No,I use another one.

Comment: rhen post the complete code how you set those spans

Comment: @pskink Thank you.I found what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `getSpans()` in specific span(That I want to reset for it) to get it's span and then I use `removeSpan` to remove it:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
ss.setSpan(new URLSpan("com://my.app"), 3, 6,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
URLSpan[] toRemoveSpans = ss.getSpans(3, 6, URLSpan.class);
ss.removeSpan(toRemoveSpans[0]);   
ss.setSpan(new MyURLSpan("com://my.app"), 3, 6,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```